# Using JQuery to display a div based upon a content of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery so that when somebody goes to this exact page: www.mysite.com/somedirectory/somesubdirectory divwhite appears and divgrey is hidden.  This code works. However, I was wondering if there is someway to write the code so that it checks to see if somesubdirectory is two directories lower than the root level and not dependent if somedirectory is there or not in case somedirectory's name changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myvariable = $(location).attr('href');  
if(myvariable.indexOf("/somedirectory/somesubdirectory") > -1) {
$("#divgrey").hide();
$("#divwhite").show();
}
else {    
 j$("#divgrey").show();
  $("#divwhite").hide();

}

});
```

Comment: This solution is working? Anyway i think that you should create a variable or something from the back-end that identifies if this code should be executed or not... For example with an Ajax call

Comment: Does my solution help you Ellie? If so, please accept it; otherwise, let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one line of vanilla JavaScript

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').length
```

If this number equals 3, the path name contains two slashes and you are in a subdirectory two levels below the root directory, independent of their names.

Note that this assumes that you take care of trailing slashes in the URL in your .htaccess.